# SQL Server: Inserting into table with INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2016

This [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) states that the "rules regarding when an INSERT or UPDATE statement referencing a table with an INSTEAD OF trigger must supply values for columns are the same as if the table did not have an INSTEAD OF trigger".

However:

```
CREATE TABLE tbTriggerTest (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tgTriggerTest
ON dbo.tbTriggerTest
INSTEAD OF INSERT
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
GO

INSERT tbTriggerTest DEFAULT VALUES
GO
```

does not throw an error even though at the INSERT statement level I'm inserting a null value into the primary key. In fact INSERTED.id is NULL in this case. So is the documentation incorrect OR does it only apply inside the trigger?

**EDIT:** Responding to a proposed answer stating that caller must supply some value for a non null column, even if it is null, the following does not throw an error yet arguably does not supply any value for column `ij`.

```
CREATE TABLE tbTriggerTest2
(
    id INT,
    ij INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (id, ij)
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tgTriggerTest2
   ON  dbo.tbTriggerTest2
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED;
END
GO

INSERT tbTriggerTest2 (id) VALUES (0)
GO
```

Comment: Your trigger just selects... which is trying to return a result-set from a trigger, which is deprecated. It's not actually inserting anything. It should read "INSERT INTO tblTriggerTest SELECT * FROM inserted" instead.

Comment: I know @pmbAustin, it is just the to show that the rules do change when a trigger is on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) that you referenced say:

> The following rules regarding when an INSERT or UPDATE statement
>   referencing a table with an INSTEAD OF trigger must supply values for
>   columns are the same as if the table did not have an INSTEAD OF
>   trigger:
>
> - INSERT statements must supply values for all NOT NULL columns that do not have DEFAULT constraints.

Your `INSERT` statement in the question

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest DEFAULT VALUES
```

supplies values for all columns. It does not omit any column. Yes, it supplies `NULL` values, but the docs don't say that `INSERT` statement should supply **non-null** values. It says that `INSERT` statement should mention all non-null columns. This is what the parser checks - the list of columns.

Actual `INSERT` operation will fail later when a `NOT NULL` constraint will be violated. In your example the actual `INSERT` never happens, so you don't see any errors.

---

It is the same as if you didn't have any triggers on the table and tried to run

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest VALUES (NULL)
```

The server will parse the statement, see that `VALUES` clause has the same list of columns as the table and try to execute the `INSERT`. It will fail with constraint violation.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table
>   'AdventureWorks2014.dbo.tbTriggerTest'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

You can try to get an estimated execution plan and you'll get a plan. The engine generated a plan and started executing it.

---

If you try to run

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest VALUES (NULL, NULL)
```

The statement will fail without attempt to be executed.

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

If you try to get an estimated execution plan you will not get one. The engine can't generate a plan, because list of columns don't match.

### Second example

In the second example both `id` and `ij` columns are nullable. So, again, with the trigger or without a trigger the engine will accept `INSERT` statement with only one value. The second value will be assumed to be `NULL`.

If `VALUES`  clause has less columns than in the table, then missing columns are assumed to be `NULL` by the engine (or, more precisely, DEFAULT). So, in your example a table has two columns, and the statement

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest2 (id) VALUES (0)
```

is the same as:

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest2 (id, ij) VALUES (0, NULL)
```

The second column is nullable, so it has a default `NULL` value. You can specify a different default value of a column and `INSERT` will also work as expected if you don't include this column in the list of columns.

If you change the definition of the table to be:

```
CREATE TABLE tbTriggerTest2
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    ij INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (id, ij)
)
```

then without the trigger the following statement would fail:

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest2 (id) VALUES (0)
```

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ij', table
>   'dbo.tbTriggerTest2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

With the trigger the whole statement will run successfully, because the trigger suppresses the attempt to insert a row with a `NULL` value into a column that doesn't accept `NULL`.

---

If you change the definition of the table to be:

```
CREATE TABLE tbTriggerTest3
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    ij INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 10
)
```

then

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest3 (id) VALUES (0)
```

would work the same as:

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest3 (id, ij) VALUES (0, 10)
```

And it will succeed with or without the trigger.

On the other hand,

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest3 (id) VALUES (NULL)
```

is the same as:

```
INSERT tbTriggerTest3 (id, ij) VALUES (NULL, 10)
```

and it will fail without the trigger

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table
>   'dbo.tbTriggerTest3'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

, because it will try to insert `NULL` into `id`, which doesn't accept NULLs

With the trigger that suppresses inserting of the row it will succeed.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod, I added explanations for the second example